# JS functions inside of loops - Memory/CPU Considerations

Tags: javascript, function, closures

Can someone tell me if this has any affect on CPU or memory??

```
    Object.keys(app.crypto).forEach(symbol => {
        txRec(0, symbol, tx_recs)
        function txRec(tx_index, symbol, tx_recs) {
           ...
        }
    })
```

vs.

```
    Object.keys(app.crypto).forEach(symbol => {
        txRec(0, symbol, tx_recs)
    })
    function txRec(tx_index, symbol, tx_recs) {
      ...
    }
```

I went with the latter of course as it makes more natural sense to me.  It would seem that the function is being redeclared in the loop in the first case.  Does anyone have any incite in regards to this?  Just curious.

Comment: Why do you declare a function at all instead of just putting the `...` code directly in the `forEach` callback? Apparantly `txRec` is called nowhere else.

Comment: @Bergi - Callback hell, it keeps the code cleaner by not indenting too far into the body of the editor.  I did not post the full code for txRec here, notice the "...", so it's harder to see that in the example I provided.

txRec is also a recursive function as well.

Answer (score 1):

> It would seem that the function is being redeclared in the loop

No, it would maybe create a closure, but in your case thats unlikely. In a good js engine the differences get optimized away, and both are totally equal.

Comment: This is exactly what I had figured, thanks for the response!